# Spring boot application, integration of log4j, no file is created whenusing rolling file appender

Tags: spring-boot, log4j2

In my spring boot application I wanna add logging, for that I tried to use log4j2

This my log4j2.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN" monitorInterval="30">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="LOG_PATTERN">           
            %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %5p ${hostName} --- [%15.15t] %-40.40c{1.} : %m%n%ex
        </Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="ConsoleAppender" target="SYSTEM_OUT"
            follow="true">
           <PatternLayout pattern="${LOG_PATTERN}" />
        </Console>

    <!-- Rolling File Appender -->
    <RollingFile name="FileAppender"
        fileName="logs/log4j2-demo.log"
        filePattern="logs/log4j2-demo-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log">
        <PatternLayout>
            <Pattern>${LOG_PATTERN}</Pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10MB" />
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10" />
    </RollingFile>

   </Appenders>
<Loggers>
    <Logger name="tn.manual.controller" level="debug"
        additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleAppender" />
         <AppenderRef ref="FileAppender"/>
    </Logger>

    <Root level="info">
        <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleAppender" />
         <AppenderRef ref="FileAppender"/>
    </Root>
</Loggers>
```

In the console, I can see the log messages.
But NO file is created, the logs folder should I create it before? 
Really, I'm disturbed, I should finish this task today.
I need your help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- This the default configuration path of logback if you want to modify 
    the location please provide its entry in application.properties file as value 
    of logging.config key -->

<configuration scan="false">
    <property name="logPattern"
        value="%-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n" />
    <property name="logEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    <property name="logDirectory" value="logs" />
    <property name="file_base_name" value="Your service name" />
    <property name="archive" value="archive" />
    <timestamp key="current_date" datePattern="yyyy-MM-dd" />

    <!-- Shut down hook registered to close logging factory Elegantly . -->
    <shutdownHook class="ch.qos.logback.core.hook.DelayingShutdownHook" />


    <appender name="fileAppender"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${logDirectory}/${file_base_name}.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${logDirectory}/${archive}/${file_base_name}_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
            </fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>30MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <charset>${logEncoding}</charset>
            <pattern>${logPattern}</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>


    <appender name="ANALYTICS-FILE"
              class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${logDirectory}/${file_base_name}_error</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${logDirectory}/${archive}/${file_base_name}_error_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
            </fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>30MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <charset>${logEncoding}</charset>
            <pattern>${logPattern}</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <!--<logger name="analytics" level="INFO" additivity="false">-->
        <!--<appender-ref ref="ANALYTICS-FILE"/>-->
    <!--</logger>-->
    <!-- <appender name="ASYNC500" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender"> 
        <appender-ref ref="fileAppender"/> <queueSize>5000</queueSize> <discardingThreshold>0</discardingThreshold> 
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" /> </appender> -->


    <!-- Only use this appender when you are developing your application but 
        during production it is advisable to disable logging to console to reduce 
        latency in logging as it costs more I/O time. -->

    <appender name="stdout" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} %highlight(%-5level)
                %logger{36}.%M - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <!-- Configuration for loggers ,Loggers who do not have logging level defined 
     will inherit levels from root
    -->
    <root level="error">
        <appender-ref ref="ANALYTICS-FILE"/>
    </root>

    <root level="info" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="ANALYTICS-FILE"/>
    </root>
    <!--        -->

    <root level="WARN" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="fileAppender" />
        <appender-ref ref="stdout" />
    </root>

    <logger name="Your package name" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="fileAppender"/>
        <appender-ref ref="stdout" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.springframework.web" level="WARN" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="fileAppender"/>
        <appender-ref ref="stdout" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="org.apache.commons.beanutils.converters" level="WARN" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="fileAppender"/>
        <appender-ref ref="stdout" />
    </logger>


</configuration>
```

I hope this will help. If it will help, you can accept it as your accepted answer.
Thanks,

Comment: @senior,  I'm using the same file in spring boot and its working fine without any issues.  There might be some other issues.

Comment: logDirectory do you have already the logs directory, or it's created for you when you launch your app?
And where it's created exacty under main/resources ?

Comment: @senior LogDirectory will be created named as archive under your project root directory. The recent log will be saved in a file named servicename.log and error log will be printed in a file named servicename_error.log.

Comment: I reused exactly your log4j2.xml file and I added in application.proerties:
logging.level.org.springframework.web=INFO
logging.level.guru.springframework.blogs.controllers=INFO
logging.level.org.hibernate=ERROR
logging.file=logs/log.log
log4j.logger.org.thymeleaf=DEBUG
and it works :)
thanks @Pawan Tiwari

Comment: @senior, I'm glad to know, I could help.